# Why can't i specify constructor restrictions for type parameters besides : new()

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an interface ' `Something<T>` and wanted to restrict `T` to have a constructor with one int parameter. I can do something like `where : new()`. So why can't i make it `where T : new(int)`?

Comment: [Here](http://blog.ryjones.org/2005/07/12/product-development/)

Comment: Because that feature is not implemented

Comment: Because that's not very generic? At what point would you stop? This feature makes little sense.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Not only is that feature not implemented, it has not even been specified. That is, de facto, that feature does not exist, except as an idea.

Comment: I was wondering if there was any reason that would make it no possible to be implemented. I am not discussing whether it is generic enough or not.

Comment: It probably boils down to the same reason why you cannot specify constructors in interfaces.

Comment: @stakx: What is being sought is a constraint which would indicate that constructors must be available with particular signatures. Such a thing would be useful in many factory-method and deserialization scenarios.

Comment: @supercat: I understand that perfectly, and I do not doubt that many people would find such `new(…)` constraints useful. In many situations, being able to simply use `new` might feel far less kludgy than having to circumvent that missing feature using e.g. factory methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can side step this by deferring instantiation of the T to the user. Something like:

```
class MyTCreator<TParam, T>
{
    private Func<TParam, T> generator;
    public MyTCreator(Func<TParam, T> generator)
    {
        this.generator=generator;
    }
    public T CreateT(TParam param)
    {
        return generator(param);
    }
}
```

and use your class like this:

```
var creator = new MyTCreator<long, DateTime>(ticks => new DateTime(ticks));
DateTime dt = creator.CreateT(12345L);
```